# How to clear input field in Draft-js

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

None of the demos that I've seen for Draft-js (by Facebook, built on React) show how to clear the input field after submit. For example, see this [code pen linked to from awesome-draft-js](http://codepen.io/rkpasia/full/jqbrpq) where the value you submit remains in the input field after submit. There's also no  [function in the api](https://facebook.github.io/draft-js/docs/api-reference-editor-state.html#content) that seems designed to do it. What I've done to achieve that is to create a new empty state on button submission like this

```
onSubmit(){
this.setState({
   editorState: EditorState.createEmpty(),
})
}
```

However, since I create an empty state in the constructor when the editor is loaded like this

```
  this.state = {
    editorState: EditorState.createEmpty(),
  };
```

I'm worried that I might not be doing it in the right way i.e. the previous state object might become a memory leak. Question: what is the intended way to reset the state in the above situation (i.e. button submit)

Comment: I created an example of what you are after and it seems to work okay. I've filled the draft-js editor with some default content on mount. Clicking the submit button empties the state using the `EditorState.createEmpty()` function.  Seems fine.  http://www.webpackbin.com/NkNbdZlXZ

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It is **NOT** recommended to use EditorState.createEmpty() to clear the state of the editor -- you should only use createEmpty on initialization.

**The proper way to reset content of the editor:**

```
import { EditorState, ContentState } from 'draft-js';

const editorState = EditorState.push(this.state.editorState, ContentState.createFromText(''));
this.setState({ editorState });
```

@source: https://github.com/draft-js-plugins/draft-js-plugins/blob/master/FAQ.md

Comment: You may want to pass the third parameter too. `EditorState.push(editorState, ContentState.createFromText(''), 'remove-range')`

Comment: any explanations why it's not recommended to use `EditorState.createEmpty()`? It works good for me.

Comment: @Stalinko it might induce `getEditorState is not a function` error someday.

Comment: This answer is not correct. This answer indeed messes with the cursor on the next input. @Fabian's answer should be selected as the correct answer

Comment: cursor bug will happen with this solution, but to fix that add this line `editorRef.current.focus()` after update the state.

Answer (score 9):

@Vikram Mevasiya's solution does not clear block list styles correctly

@Sahil's solution messes with the cursor on the next input

I found that this is the only working solution:

```js
// https://github.com/jpuri/draftjs-utils/blob/master/js/block.js
const removeSelectedBlocksStyle = (editorState)  => {
    const newContentState = RichUtils.tryToRemoveBlockStyle(editorState);
    if (newContentState) {
        return EditorState.push(editorState, newContentState, 'change-block-type');
    }
    return editorState;
}

// https://github.com/jpuri/draftjs-utils/blob/master/js/block.js
export const getResetEditorState = (editorState) => {
    const blocks = editorState
        .getCurrentContent()
        .getBlockMap()
        .toList();
    const updatedSelection = editorState.getSelection().merge({
        anchorKey: blocks.first().get('key'),
        anchorOffset: 0,
        focusKey: blocks.last().get('key'),
        focusOffset: blocks.last().getLength(),
    });
    const newContentState = Modifier.removeRange(
        editorState.getCurrentContent(),
        updatedSelection,
        'forward'
    );

    const newState = EditorState.push(editorState, newContentState, 'remove-range');
    return removeSelectedBlocksStyle(newState)
}
```

Its a combination of two helper functions provided by https://github.com/jpuri/draftjs-utils .
Didn't want to `npm install` the entire package for this.
It resets the cursor state but keeps the block list styling. This is removed by applying `removeSelectedBlocksStyle()`
I just can't belive how a library this mature doesn't offer a one-line reset feature.

Comment: Some more context here: https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/issues/1630

Comment: This answer is the winner.

Answer (score 3):

**Try this**

```
    let editorState = this.state.editorState
    let contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent()
    const firstBlock = contentState.getFirstBlock()
    const lastBlock = contentState.getLastBlock()
    const allSelected = new SelectionState({
        anchorKey: firstBlock.getKey(),
        anchorOffset: 1,
        focusKey: lastBlock.getKey(),
        focusOffset: lastBlock.getLength(),
        hasFocus: true
    })
    contentState = Modifier.removeRange(contentState, allSelected, 'backward')
    editorState = EditorState.push(editorState, contentState, 'remove-range')
    editorState = EditorState.forceSelection(contentState, contentState.getSelectionAfter())
    this.setState({editorState})
```

Answer (score 1):

1. 

```js
const content = {
  entityMap: {},
  blocks:[
    { 
      key: "637gr",
      text: "",
      type:"unstyled",
      depth:0,
      inlineStyleRanges:[],
      entityRanges: [],
      data: {}
    }
  ]
};
```

2. `const [editorContent, setEditorContent] = useState(content);`
3. `<Editor contentState={editorContent} />`

`contentState` prop does the trick after saving you can use `setEditorContent` to reset the editor

```js
setEditorContent(content)
```